# Redirect to SharePoint Hosted app when user lands on Site collection

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

Is it possible to redirect user directly to SharePoint hosted app when he enters to the site collection?
Currently user have to click on the app to navigate to SharePoint hosted app and I would like them to directly navigate to app without any clicks required.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.JS', 'sp.ClientContext', function() {
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var appInstances = SP.AppCatalog.getAppInstances(ctx, web);
ctx.load(appInstances);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
          window.location = 
 appInstances.getItemAtIndex(1).get_appWebFullUrl();

    },
    function(sender, args) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
    });
});
</script>
```